# For a single Sqlite row, faster to do 5 UPDATEs or build a python dict, then 1 Update?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have several million rows in a Sqlite database that need 5 columns updated. Each row/column value is different, so I have to update each row individually.

Because of the way I'm looping through JSON from an external API, for each row, I have the option of either:

1) do 5 `UPDATE` operations, one for value.

2) build a temporary dict in python, then unpack it into a single `UPDATE` operation that updates all 5 columns at once.

Basically I'm trading off Python time (slower language, but in memory) for SQLite time (faster language, but on disk).

Which is faster?

Comment: ...try it and see ... although I would bet creating a dict in python and doing a single update beats it by a long shot

Comment: It may not be relevant in your use case, but a single `UPDATE` per row does mean that a row can't end up in a part-updated state.

Comment: Yeah, in my case it's actually slightly better if a row gets partially updated because if something breaks partway through the 5 metrics, if the ones that worked are committed, I only need to retrieve the remaining ones. However, at this point in the code, I already have the JSON dump, so it won't be broken by network issues, only by improper JSON parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Building a dict doesn't really take that much memory. It's much more efficient since you'll only need to do one operation - and let SQLite handle it. Well, python is going to clean the dict anyway, so this is definitely the way to go.

But as @JoranBeasley mentioned in the comment.. You never know until you try.

Hope this helps!